# Use tornado future to fetch url, two different ways get different results

Tags: python, tornado, future

I want to use tornado to fetch batch urls. So my code shows below:

```
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient    
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop    


class BatchHttpClient(object):    
    def __init__(self, urls, timeout=20):    
        self.async_http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()    
        self.urls = urls    
        self.timeout = 20    

    def __mid(self):    
        results = []    
        for url in self.urls:    
            future = Future()    

            def f_callback(f1):    
                future.set_result(f1.result())    

            f = self.async_http_client.fetch(url)    
            f.add_done_callback(f_callback)    
            results.append(future)    
        return results    

    def get_batch(self):    
        results = IOLoop.current().run_sync(self.__mid)    
        return results    


urls = ["http://www.baidu.com?v={}".format(i) for i in range(10)]    
batch_http_client = BatchHttpClient(urls)    
print batch_http_client.get_batch()
```

When I run the code, an error occurs:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <function f_callback at 0x7f35458cae60> for <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7f35458c9650>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 317, in _set_done
    cb(self)
  File "/home/q/www/base_data_manager/utils/async_util.py", line 21, in f_callback
    future.set_result(f1.result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 271, in set_result
    self._set_done()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 315, in _set_done
    for cb in self._callbacks:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But if I change the code like:

```
class BatchHttpClient(object):
    def __init__(self, urls, timeout=20):
        self.async_http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        self.urls = urls
        self.timeout = 20

    def _get_batch(self, url):
        future = Future()
        f = self.async_http_client.fetch(url)
        def callback(f1):
            print future
            print f1.result()

            future.set_result(f1.result())
            print '---------'
        f.add_done_callback(callback)
        return future

    def __mid(self):
        results = []
        for url in self.urls:
            results.append(self._get_batch(url))
        return results

    def get_batch(self):
        results = IOLoop.current().run_sync(self.__mid)
        return results


urls = ["http://www.baidu.com?v={}".format(i) for i in range(10)]
batch_http_client = BatchHttpClient(urls)
for result in batch_http_client.get_batch():
    print result.body
```

Then it works.
What I do is just add a mid-function,why the results are different.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, the problem is that by the time your callbacks execute, the value of `future` is the last value set by the loop. In other words, when this executes:

```
def f_callback(f1):    
    future.set_result(f1.result())
```

the value of `future` is always the same. You can see this if you add a `print future`: the object's address will always be the same.

In your second snippet, each future and each callback are created in a function called by the loop. So each callback gets its value for `future` *from a new scope*, which fixes the problem.

Another way to fix the issue would be to modify `__mid` like this:

```
def __mid(self):
    results = []
    for url in self.urls:
        future = Future()

        def make_callback(future):
            def f_callback(f1):
                future.set_result(f1.result())
            return f_callback

        f = self.async_http_client.fetch(url)
        f.add_done_callback(make_callback(future))
        results.append(future)
    return results
```

By creating the callback in `make_callback(future)`, the value of `future` in the callbacks comes from a different scope for each callback.

Comment: My God, Thanks, It solves my problem. I doubt if `async_http_client.fetch(url)` runs fast enough, the problem will still exist?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the internals of `IOLoop` to say for sure. However, I would not write code that depends on `async_http_client.fetch(url)` running "fast enough". That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks.It's usefull for me.

Answer (score 0):

Louis's answer is correct, but I'd like to suggest a few simpler alternatives.

First, you could use `functools.partial` instead of a `make_callback` wrapper function:

```
def __mid(self):    
    results = []    
    for url in self.urls:    
        future = Future()    

        def f_callback(output, input):    
            output.set_result(f1.result())    

        f = self.async_http_client.fetch(url)
        # partial() binds the current value of future to
        # the output argument.
        f.add_done_callback(functools.partial(f_callback, future))
        results.append(future)    
    return results
```

But the intermediate `Future` looks completely unnecessary. This is equivalent to:

```
def __mid(self):
    return [self.async_http_client.fetch(url) for url in self.urls]
```

Personally I would make `__mid` a coroutine:

```
@gen.coroutine
def __mid(self):
    return (yield [self.async_http_client.fetch_url(url) for url in self.urls])
```

If you don't want to use coroutines, you may prefer to pass a callback to `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch` instead of using `Future.add_done_callback` on its result.