# python tornado async client

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I created batch delayed http (async) client which allows to trigger multiple async http requests and most importantly it allows to delay the start of requests so for example 100 requests are not triggered at a time.

But it has an issue. The http .fetch() method has a handleMethod parameter which handles the response, but I found out that if the delay (sleep) after the fetch isn't long enough the handle method is not even triggered. (maybe the request is killed or what meanwhile).

It is probably related to .run_sync method. How to fix that? I want to put delays but dont want this issue happen.

I need to parse the response regardless how long the request takes, regardless the following sleep call (that call has another reason as i said, and should not be related to response handling at all)

```
class BatchDelayedHttpClient:

  def __init__(self, requestList):
    # class members
    self.httpClient = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    self.requestList = requestList
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(self.execute)

  @gen.coroutine
  def execute(self):
    print("exec start")
    for request in  self.requestList:
        print("requesting " + request["url"])
        self.httpClient.fetch(request["url"], request["handleMethod"], method=request["method"], headers=request["headers"], body=request["body"])
        yield gen.sleep(request["sleep"])
    print("exec end")
```

Comment: Issue #1: You didn't yield the fetch.

Comment: aha so put sleep before fetch and yield the fetch? good idea :D i think i saw somewhere yield the sleep so i did that and didn't think about your solution

Comment: I thought you had to yield everything that returned a Future inside a coroutine, and fetch returns a Future...

Comment: you are right. correct solution seems to be yield both sleep and fetch. thanks

Comment: if you require sleep to be executed serially after the fetch, you may need to use `add_done_callback`? Like `yield self.httpClient.fetch().add_done_callback(lambda: yield gen.sleep...)` ...?

Comment: aha thanks. well i don't insist if it should be before the fetch or after the callback, but if i just put yield sleep and yield fetch after each other it worked just as i needed, that means requests seems to be delayed and not triggered at once. another issue is that if the handling method takes too long some requests may fail on connection timeout but maybe i will fix it by extending the timeout value. i do actually bulk db inserts after the fetch calling inserts one by one. maybe i will try some bulk inserts like using pypyodbc instead of pyodbc and saving the csv i will see.

Comment: Related: [Use tornado future to fetch url, two different ways get different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565024/use-tornado-future-to-fetch-url-two-different-ways-get-different-results)